# How do I loop through nested Models in CanJS

Tags: javascript, json, loops, model, canjs

I receive nested JSON data through a Model.

How do I loop through nested data in the model I pass my view file in CanJs ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a can.Observe.List using your json data. Then pass that list to the view.
In the view you can use the list helper. Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/efihey/1/edit